# Chrome how to disable session restore notification when restarting after power loss

Tags: google-chrome

After three days of trying to resolve this issues I now need some help. I have a web page that runs on Google Chrome Version 60.0.3112.113. What I need to do is to disable the notification that pops up if the device has power loss. At the moment when the device restarts, Chrome auto starts and load the URL along with the notification concerning session restore. I have read many ways of disabling this notification but none of them work with version 60.0.3112.113.

Can anyone please advise me on the best way to resolve this issue.

Many thanks in advance for your time.